# save div as image and save to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I would like to know how I to save my div image to database. I already know that I cannot save the actual image into database, I have to save the name of the image and link it to a folder called images. I can take the image of the div that is not the problem the problem is how do I save the image to a folder and link the name to database I know how to do it with regular images i just dont know how to do it with div as image. im using mysqli code for php i don't know if that matters. here is my code i need to save the image that was created with a unique name.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 
var element = $("#firstshirt"); // global variable
var getCanvas; // global variable
 
    $("#btn-Preview-Image").on('click', function () {
         html2canvas(element, {
         onrendered: function (canvas) {
                $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
                getCanvas = canvas;
             }
         });
    });

 $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function () {
    var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    // Now browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
    var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
    $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").attr("download", "your_pic_name.png").attr("href", newData);
 });

});
```

```html
<input id="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Preview"/>
    <a id="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
```

Comment: You CAN actually save a image in a database if you i.e. base64 it. Question is if this is useful/generally a good idea

Comment: i did find that code but i didnt find out how i can save it to a folder and name to database do you have any idea of how to save ?

Comment: As I said, you could store the image directly in the database, but if you want to save it in a folder, just copy the uploaded image into the right directory (copy function) and then save the Name of the file into the database

Comment: i will give it a try thank you

Comment: have you tried http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ ??

Comment: @mariusz yes i have tried that i cant find a way to upload to database